# MySql Long Running Query Fails on Docker .NET Core: Attempted to read past the end of the stream / Expected to read 4 header bytes but only received 0

Tags: c#, mysql, docker, .net-core

I am attempting to query a MySql database with 95M rows with a query that has a where clause on a non-indexed column (*please don't judge, I have no control over that part as the server is not ours*).

I've tried both MySqlConnector and MySqlClient with the same result. Consistently, after 5 minutes, they both error:

Using **MySqlConnector**:

> Expected to read 4 header bytes but only received 0.

Using **MySql.Data.MySqlClient**:

> Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

This **only happens in a docker container** (running Docker Desktop on Windows the `aspnet:3.1-buster-slim` image, but I've tried others with the same result).

Running the same code via a IIS express hosted web api or a console app works fine.

The connection string specifies `Connect Timeout=21600; Default Command Timeout=21600; MinPoolSize=0;` and I've tried various Min/Max pool size configs and turning pooling off with no luck.

I have tried changing the connection string `SslMode` to `None` with no change.

The code to query the data is pretty straight forward:

```
protected virtual async IAsyncEnumerable<List<object>> GetDataAsync(string connectionString, string sql, int timeout = 21600, IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
{
    await using var conn = new MySqlConnection { ConnectionString = connectionString };
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    using var trans = await conn.BeginTransactionAsync(isolationLevel);
    await using var cmd = new MySqlCommand { Connection = conn, CommandText = sql, CommandTimeout = timeout, Transaction = trans };
    await using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
    {
        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
            reader.GetValues(values);
            yield return values.Select(v => v is DBNull ? null : v).ToList();
        }
    }

    await trans.CommitAsync();
}
```

I have tried with and without the transaction - no change.

If I try a simpler query, I get results back w/o issue using that same `GetDataAsync` method. Even stranger, other long-running queries are working fine too. If I try to do a similar, non-indexed, query on a table with 30M rows, it runs past the 5 minute mark and eventually (over an hour) returns results.

Running `show variables` yields the following (none of which seem to point to the issue):

- connect_timeout  10
- delayed_insert_timeout   300
- innodb_flush_log_at_timeout  1
- innodb_lock_wait_timeout 50
- innodb_rollback_on_timeout   OFF
- interactive_timeout  28800
- lock_wait_timeout    31536000
- net_read_timeout 30
- net_write_timeout    60
- rpl_stop_slave_timeout   31536000
- slave_net_timeout    3600
- wait_timeout 28800

Is there some kind of idle network timeout occurring in the docker container?

Comment: Thanks for a thorough question with all the relevant details. But I can't figure out why the 30M row query would run for an hour, but the 95M row query would time out right at 5 minutes. Have you tried `KeepAlive=120` in the connection string to force TCP keepalive packets? (The MySqlConnector documentation is out-of-date; that option should be respected and implemented on Linux with `netcoreapp3.0` or later.)

Comment: Winner!!! Thank you, @BradleyGrainger!! If you want to just write that as an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: What is the version of mysql and your referenced MySql.Data library? Had faced simialr issue some time back

Comment: @KamranShahid I tried it with the latest version of MySql.Data (v8.0.21) and MySqlConnector (v1.0.1). Thanks to Bradley, I was able to get it to work with MySqlConnector and ```KeepAlive=120```. I did not try it with MySql.Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Keepalive=120` in your connection string; this will send TCP keepalive packets every two minutes (120 seconds) which should stop the connection from being closed. (You may need to adjust the `Keepalive` value for your particular situation.)

Note that if you're using MySqlConnector on Linux, due to limitations of .NET Core, this option is only implemented on .NET Core 3.0 (or later).

Comment: i think he is using .net core 3.1